# Typing in a tkinter entry using a button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm working on a small program and I'm having trouble with one part where I wanted to create something like a keyboard in a tkinter window.

The code for the window template is following:

```
main_screen = Tk()
main_screen.title("keyboard")
main_screen.geometry("200x200")

Btn_1 = Button(main_screen,text="á")
Btn_1.place(x=90,y=100,anchor='center')
Btn_2 = Button(main_screen,text="ñ")
Btn_2.place(x=110,y=100,anchor='center')
Btn_3 = Button(main_screen,text="í")
Btn_3.place(x=130,y=100,anchor='center')  
Btn_4 = Button(main_screen,text="ú")
Btn_4.place(x=70,y=100,anchor='center')  

entry_1 = Entry(main_screen)
entry_1.place(x=100,y=130,anchor='center')

entry_2 = Entry(main_screen)
entry_2.place(x=100,y=150,anchor='center')



main_screen.mainloop()
```

What I'd like to achieve is for the program to type chosen letters in the entry_1 or entry_2 spots(depending which one is currently clicked with flickering indicator), based on which button I press, since I don't have the buttons on my keyboard and I don't want to change the language nor use the Alt + signs combinations.

I can't find anything that would help me get such result, I'd appreciate any tips

If I was unclear about anything, do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know which entry is selected by setting a variable when an entry is selected.

Second create a function which is called when a button is clicked.  Inside the function, insert the corresponding character to the selected entry.

Below is a modified example based on your code:

```
from tkinter import *

current_entry = None # hold the reference to the selected entry

def on_focus_in(event):
    global current_entry
    current_entry = event.widget # save the selected entry

def on_focus_out(event):
    global current_entry
    current_entry = None

def send_key(key):
    if current_entry:
        current_entry.insert('insert', key) # insert the key to the selected entry

main_screen = Tk()
main_screen.title("keyboard")
main_screen.geometry("200x200")

Btn_1 = Button(main_screen, text="á", command=lambda:send_key("á"))
Btn_1.place(x=90, y=100, anchor='center')
Btn_2 = Button(main_screen, text="ñ", command=lambda:send_key("ñ"))
Btn_2.place(x=110, y=100, anchor='center')
Btn_3 = Button(main_screen, text="í", command=lambda:send_key("í"))
Btn_3.place(x=130, y=100, anchor='center')  
Btn_4 = Button(main_screen, text="ú", command=lambda:send_key("ú"))
Btn_4.place(x=70, y=100, anchor='center')  

entry_1 = Entry(main_screen)
entry_1.place(x=100, y=130, anchor='center')
entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', on_focus_in)
entry_1.bind('<FocusOut>', on_focus_out)

entry_2 = Entry(main_screen)
entry_2.place(x=100, y=150, anchor='center')
entry_2.bind('<FocusIn>', on_focus_in)
entry_2.bind('<FocusOut>', on_focus_out)

main_screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you is simple. Code below:

```
entry_name = Entry(main_screen)
entry_name.pack()
button_name = Button(main_screen, text="character_here", command = lambda x: insert("same character given in text option")
button_name.pack()
```

For the `insert()` function, give the code like this:

```
def insert(character):
    old_entry_content = entry_name.get()
    entry_name.delete(0, END)
    entry_name.insert(0, old_entry + str(character))
```

Comment: Your code will not work as it should. As you are calling the function directly which is returning `None` to the `command` parameter of `Button`. You need to return the function itself without any parathesis that can be called later when the button is pressed.

Comment: see you should say `command = lambda: insert("same character given in text option")` and also `old_entry` is undefined

Comment: Oops! Sorry guys! I forgot that part to be written even though I had reminded myself eariler. My bad! Thanks @CoolCloud and @ Saad for reminding